# Bootstrap & heroku 12 factor gem - Styles not showing up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, heroku, assets

I installed Bootstrap with the gem [twitter-bootstrap-rails](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails). When pushing to Heroku the styles weren't showing up, so I changed my config/production.rb. I changed this:

```
config.cache_classes = true
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.digest = true
```

These made the styles of Bootstrap to show up correctly. Then I read that heroku had a gem that dealt with the assets on production (12_factor) so I put it in and changed the config/production.rb again to:

```
config.cache_classes = false
config.serve_static_assets = false
config.assets.compile = false
config.assets.digest = false
```

But this makes Bootstrap styles to disappear again. What am I doing wrong here? What am I missing?

I also tried to put the config.serve_static_assets = false to true, but that did not help either.

Comment: I added "gem 'rails_12factor'" to a Rails 3.2 app to suppress vendor/plugin/* deprecation warnings on Heroku, and also found that this made the Boostrap styles disappear.  Why?

Answer (score 0):

do you have this in your application.css?

```
*= require bootstrap_and_overrides
```

Did you try running> 
    heroku labs:enable user-env-compile -a myapp

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-user-env-compile